# Hide geometry generator symbol from layers panel in QGIS

Tags: qgis

Could someone tell me if it is possible to generate a geometry in a QGIS layer and not show this generated geometry in the layer panel?

So that the symbol in the layer panel becomes static, in a way that only the main symbol appears.

[image]

main symbol:

[image]

I'm not using callouts, in this case, because I can't create the formats I need.

However, I checked that there is a possibility to create a geometry generator in callouts, but I couldn't. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: yes, it makes sense.
Thank you very much

Comment: Good question, I have also wondered about this. In the print layout, you can create a custom symbol for the legend, it would be nice to have that ability to customise symbols in the layer panel too.